# Can't find control with name email, cant find control with name pwd also onSubmit is not defined

Tags: angular

We are trying to validate a form with reactive form validation. It seems not working on the console it shows errors can't find the control with the name of email and can't find the control with the name of pwd. It's a simple sign in form. Here is the code:

```
    <form action="" [formGroup]="customerSigninForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input _ngcontent-c0="" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="email" type="text"
       id="email"
      formControlName="email"
    >
    <span
      *ngIf="!customerSigninForm.get('customerData.email').valid && customerSigninForm.get('customerData.email').touched"
      class="help-block">Please enter a valid email!</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Password" type="password"
            formControlName="pwd"   
            >
             <span
      *ngIf="!customerSigninForm.get('customerData.pwd').valid && customerSigninForm.get('customerData.pwd').touched"
      class="help-block">Please enter a valid password!</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="extra-btns align-items-center">
             <button class="btn btn-link ">Forget Password</button>
             <button class="btn btn-link ">Forget Password</button>
         </div>
         <div>
            <button type="submit" class="  btn form-btn btn-lg btn-block">Sign In With Email</button>
         </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

**Also here is typescript**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-customer-signin',
  templateUrl: './customer-signin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer-signin.component.css']
})
export class CustomerSigninComponent implements OnInit {

  genders = ['male', 'female'];
  customerSigninForm: FormGroup;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.customerSigninForm = new FormGroup({
      'customerData': new FormGroup({
       'email': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email], this.forbiddenEmails),
       'pwd': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required,
       Validators.pattern('(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&].{8,}')
        ])

      }),
     });

  }

  onSubmit() {
   this.customerSigninForm.reset();
  }
}
```

Of course, the reactive form module is included on app modules :)
On the browser besides those console errors also nothing works from validator if you type something or click a button there is no any message at all. Just those console error and simple UI which was before. How can this be fixed? What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have a nested form group, `customerData` inside `customerSigninForm`, so to access `email` and `pwd` controls inside that group those inputs must be inside another element with `formGroupName="customerData"`. eg:

```
<form action="" [formGroup]="customerSigninForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group" formGroupName="customerData">
        <input _ngcontent-c0="" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="email" type="text" id="email" formControlName="email"/>
        <span *ngIf="!customerSigninForm.get('customerData.email').valid && customerSigninForm.get('customerData.email').touched" class="help-block">Please enter a valid email!</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" formGroupName="customerData">
        <input class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Password" type="password" formControlName="pwd"/>
        <span *ngIf="!customerSigninForm.get('customerData.pwd').valid && customerSigninForm.get('customerData.pwd').touched" class="help-block">Please enter a valid password!</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="extra-btns align-items-center">
            <button class="btn btn-link ">Forget Password</button>
            <button class="btn btn-link ">Forget Password</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="  btn form-btn btn-lg btn-block">Sign In With Email</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

But i sincerely don't see why you need that at all, just use:

```
this.customerSigninForm = new FormGroup({
       'email': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email], this.forbiddenEmails),
       'pwd': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required,
       Validators.pattern('(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&].{8,}')
        ])
     });
```

And make corresponding changes in the html:

```
<form action="" [formGroup]="customerSigninForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input _ngcontent-c0="" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="email" type="text" id="email" formControlName="email"/>
            <span *ngIf="!customerSigninForm.get('email').valid && customerSigninForm.get('email').touched" class="help-block">Please enter a valid email!</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Password" type="password" formControlName="pwd"/>
            <span *ngIf="!customerSigninForm.get('pwd').valid && customerSigninForm.get('pwd').touched" class="help-block">Please enter a valid password!</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="extra-btns align-items-center">
                <button class="btn btn-link ">Forget Password</button>
                <button class="btn btn-link ">Forget Password</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" class="  btn form-btn btn-lg btn-block">Sign In With Email</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Also I think modern browsers accept those, but it is generally better to close input tags, eg

`<input ... />`

Comment: Thanks for your help. After those fixes it shows error connected with:

onSubmit() {
   this.customerSigninForm.reset();
  };

Comment: CustomerSigninComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR ReferenceError: onSubmit is not defined

Comment: @Artyom It seems that angular cannot find that method, make sure it isn't private and try rebuilding the app

Answer (score -1):

`onSubmit()` should be out from `ngOnInit(){}`
Try this:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.customerSigninForm = new FormGroup({
       'email': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email], this.forbiddenEmails),
       'pwd': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required,
       Validators.pattern('(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&].{8,}'),
        ]);
     });
}

onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.customerSigninForm);
    this.customerSigninForm.reset();
}
```